# How can I float.TryParse on a substring of a whole line?

Tags: c#, tryparse

I'm making a text serialization system where each line contains `memberName value`. I can identify the member without allocating a substring by finding the char index of the space and using `string.Compare(line, 0, memberName, 0, indexOfSpace)`, but when I go to parse the rest of the line to get the value it seems that I need to create a substring to pass into float.TryParse (and the similar methods for other primitive types).

Are there methods like TryParse in some other class which take substring indices? Otherwise, is there somewhere I can see the source code of those methods to implement my own variations?

Comment: What's wrong with creating a substring? Are you writing code for an 8086 processor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there methods like TryParse in some other class which take substring indices?

No.

> Otherwise, is there somewhere I can see the source code of those methods to implement my own variations?

Yes, `Double.TryParse` is available in the Microsoft Reference Source repository:

- https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/double.cs,4ac3250276256193

---

As a general word of advice: In *most cases*, creating a substring is *very* unlikely to be relevant with respect to performance or memory usage. Be sure that this is *really* the bottleneck of your application before investing a lot of effort to micro-optimize here.

Comment: I know it's only a tiny bit of performance, but I'm making it for a Unity plugin which could potentially be used in strenuous situations, and Unity's garbage collector is the subject of many complaints.

That said, the source looks like a pretty complex wheel to reinvent so I don't think I'll bother.

Thanks for the answer.